# De Moivre's martingale and stopping times

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm reading Grimmett's and Stirzaker's book of probability and random processes, and there's an example on De Moivre's martingale which confuses me (pp. 492, if you want to read along).

Consider a simple random walk $(S_n)$ with $0<S_0<N$, for which each step is rightwards with probability $p$ where $0<p=1-q<1$. We know that $Y_n=(q/p)^{S_n}$ is a martingale, and furthermore the first passage time $T$ of the walk to the set $\{ 0, N\}$ is a stopping time. A standard optional stopping result gives us that $E((q/p)^{S_T})=E((q/p)^{S_0})$. None of this troubles me. My problem arrives when they write that this means that $p_k=P(S_t=0|S_0=k)$ satisfies

$p_k+(q/p)^N(1-p_k)=(q/p)^k$.

I can calculate $E((q/p)^{S_0})=(q/p)^k$, so only the left hand side bothers me. Are they using some formula I've forgotten?

Answer (score 1):

Since $S_T\in\{0,N\}$ almost surely, $E((q/p)^{S_T})=(q/p)^0P(S_T=0)+(q/p)^NP(S_T=N)$. Now, $P(S_T=0)=p_k$ (there is a typo in your definition) and $P(S_T=N)=1-p_k$ (this uses twice the fact that $T$ is finite with full probability), QED.